# Using Next router to link to a dynamically created page

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next-router

Fairly new to NextJs - I am trying to link between a category index page and a dynamically created page, which is using getServerSideProps

I have created a product template page with the following path -
`/products/[...product]`

I am trying to link to it from the index page using this code, but it is not working

```
import { useRouter } from "next/router";

const router = useRouter()

const handleClick = () => {
  const productUrl = `/products/${slug}`;
  router.push(productUrl);
};
```

The following code does work, but is not very performant

```
const handleClick = () => {
  const productUrl = `/products/${slug}`;
  window.location.replace(productUrl);
}
```

Any ideas on how to implement dynamic pages with next/router would be appreciated

Answer (score 3):

Generally, for accessibility reasons (and also to avoid perf/js issues like the one you're seeing), if a button press is meant to result in a page-change, you should use anchor tags.

In Next.Js to get performant routing, you wrap these tags in a `Link`:

```js
import Link from 'next/link'

...

<Link href={`/products/${slug}`}>
  <a> See details </a>
</Link>
```

This will then work with the dynamic `slug` from props.

Comment: Thanks - that works! And much better for a11y standards as you mentioned